# Table view error

Tags: ios, objective-c

The table view is not working when loading.It is giving an error.Here is the error.

> NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1
>   beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'**

**Here is my code**.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    uiButtonArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [SharedPreferenceUtil saveBoolValueInUserDefaults:YES forKey:@"viewupdate"];
    indexval = 0;
    if (isNotification)
    {
        isNotification = NO;
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
    [self getRemarks];
    [self updateUI];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{


    [remarksTable setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 190, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-20, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-180)];

    [Calendarscroll  setFrame:CGRectMake(0,90,320, 59)];
    [Calendarscroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    Calendarscroll.contentSize =CGSizeMake(1500, 59);
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

-(void)fillcalendar
{
    buttonIndex=0;

    for (UIButton *btn in uiButtonArray )
    {
        [btn removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [uiButtonArray removeAllObjects];
    globalDate=currentDate;
    // this is the placeholder for the calendar

    // setting up the month title
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    [monthLabel setText:[df stringFromDate:currentDate]];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:currentDate];

    // change for the first day
    [components setDay:1];
    // update the component
    components = [calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]];

    [components setDay:-[components weekday]+2];

    int lessDay = [components day];
    int month = [components month];
    int year = [components year];

    // extracting components from date
    NSDateComponents *components3 = [calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    int currentDateInteger=[components3 day];
    monthInteger=[components3 month];
    yearInteger=[components3 year];
    CGFloat orgx=0,orgy=1.0f;

    int m=month;
    for (int week=0; week<6 && month==m; week++)
    {
        for (int d=0; d<7; d++)
        {
            [components setDay:lessDay];



            int d =[[calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]] day];



            m =[[calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]] month];




            int y =[[calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:components]] year];


            NSString *daysdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d",d,m,y];
            NSDateFormatter *nwd =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [nwd setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            NSDate *notdays =[nwd dateFromString:daysdate];
            [nwd setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
            NSString *WDays =[nwd stringFromDate:notdays];

            UILabel *Weekdays =[self createLbl:WDays orgx:orgx orgy:orgy];

            UIButton *button = [self createBtn:d orgx:orgx orgy:orgy Date:currentDate];

            if (d==defaultDateInteger && defaultMonthInteger==m)
            {

                // globalButton=button;

            }

            NSString *isSunday =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d",d,m,y];
            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter  alloc]init];
            [df setDateFormat:@"d-M-yyyy"];
            NSString *cdate = [df stringFromDate:date];
            NSLog(@"CURRENT DATE: %@ \n %@", isSunday,cdate);

            //Circle the Today's Date
            if ([isSunday isEqualToString:cdate]) {
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
                // [button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            }


            [Calendarscroll addSubview:button];
            [Calendarscroll addSubview:Weekdays];

            button.tag=buttonIndex;
            [uiButtonArray addObject:button];
            // [DayArray addObject:Weekdays];
            buttonIndex++;
            orgx+=46;
            lessDay++;

        }


    }


}
- (UIButton*) createBtn:(int)day orgx:(CGFloat)orgx orgy:(CGFloat)orgy Date:(NSDate*)caldate
{



    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    NSDateFormatter *cMonth = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [cMonth setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter  alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDateFormatter *dff = [[NSDateFormatter  alloc]init];
    [dff setDateFormat:@"d"];
    NSDateFormatter *days =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [days setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
    NSString *cdate1 = [dff stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"The single date is: %@",cdate1);
    NSString *cdate = [df stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"df is: %@",cdate);
    NSString *cdays =[days stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"The days are: %@",cdays);
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.52 green:0.5 blue:0.12 alpha:0.8]];
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-14.0, -16.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", day] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(orgx, 28, 35, 30);

    return button;

}
-(UILabel*) createLbl:(NSString*)Days orgx:(CGFloat)orgx orgy:(CGFloat)orgy
{
    UILabel *Weekdays =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(orgx, 5, 35, 20)];
    NSDateFormatter *cMonth = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [cMonth setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    NSDate *Ndate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter  alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDateFormatter *days =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [days setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
    NSString *cdate = [df stringFromDate:Ndate];
    NSLog(@"df is: %@",cdate);
    NSString *cdays =[days stringFromDate:Ndate];
    NSLog(@"The days are: %@",cdays);
    [Weekdays setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.52 green:0.5 blue:0.12 alpha:0.8]];
    //Weekdays.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-14.0, -16.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    [Weekdays setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [Weekdays setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Days]];
    [Weekdays setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];

    return Weekdays;
}
-(void)CreateSection
{
    sectionsData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<collectHW.count; i++)
    {
       /* [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to    download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
        // [Sectiondata addObject:sectionarray];
        NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);*/
        //for (int i =0; i<newsArray.count; i++)

            if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"path"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
            {
                [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
            }
            else
            {
                [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]], nil]];
            }



      /*  if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"path"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
        {
            if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
            {
                if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                {

                    if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                    {
                        [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to    download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                            NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                    }else
                    {
                        [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                    }
                }else{////deadlinedate........
                    if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                    {
                        [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to    download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                        NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                    }else
                    {
                        [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                    }
                }
            }else
             {//////name........
                 if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                 {

                     if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to    download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                         NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                     }else
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                     }
                 }else{////deadlinedate........
                     if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to    download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                         NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                     }else
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap to download attachment."],@"hasAttachment",nil]];
                     }
                 }
             }
         }else
         {/////////path......

             if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
             {
                 if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                 {

                     if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],nil]];
                       //  NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                     }else
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],nil]];
                     }
                 }else{////deadlinedate........
                     if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],nil]];
                        // NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                     }else
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]],nil]];
                     }
                 }
             }else
             {//////name........
                 if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                 {

                     if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],nil]];
                       //  NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                     }else
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DUE DATE: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"deadlinedate"]],nil]];
                     }
                 }else{////deadlinedate........
                     if ([[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:BLANK_STRING]].length!=0)
                     {
                         [sectionsData addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DESCRIPTION: %@",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"description"]],nil]];
                      //   NSLog(@"The description is: %@",sectionsData);

                     }else
                     {
                         [self showDropDownViewWithmessage:@"No homework is yet to display." title:@"Message" inView:self.view];
                     }
                 }
             }
         }*/
        NSLog(@"The new data is: %@",sectionsData);
    }
    UIColor *sectionsColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:36.0f/255.0f green:158.0f/255.0f blue:110.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor *sectionTitleColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIFont *sectionTitleFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:24.0f];
    EMAccordionSection *section;
    // emTV.closedSectionIcon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_down.png"];
    // emTV.openedSectionIcon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_up.png"];

    for (int i = 0 ; i<collectHW.count; i++)
    {
        section = [[EMAccordionSection alloc] init];
        [section setBackgroundColor:sectionsColor];
        [section setItems:[sectionsData objectAtIndex:i]];
        [section setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"subjectname"],[[collectHW objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"assignmenttype"]]];
        [section setTitleFont:sectionTitleFont];
        [section setTitleColor:sectionTitleColor];
        [emTV addAccordionSection:section];

    }
    NSLog(@"The Section is: %@",section.title);
    [remarksTable reloadData];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"emCell"];
       NSMutableArray *items = [sectionsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0f,0.0f,220.0f, 40.0f)];
    [titleLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
    [titleLbl setText:[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [titleLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleLbl setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height+10, 40.0f);
    [titleLbl setFrame:CGRectMake(30, titleLbl.frame.origin.y, 280.0f, height)];
    titleLbl.numberOfLines=30;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:titleLbl];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell;
}
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //TAHomeworksTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeworkCell"];
    NSMutableArray *items = [sectionsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height+15, 40.0f);
    return height;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)",[[collectHW objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"subjectname"],[[collectHW objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"assignmenttype"]];
    NSLog(@"The text is: %@",text);
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(250.0f - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height+35, 40.0f);
    return height;
}
- (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)str_HEX  alpha:(CGFloat)alpha_range{
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;
    sscanf([str_HEX UTF8String], "#%02X%02X%02X", &red, &green, &blue);
    return  [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0 green:green/255.0 blue:blue/255.0 alpha:alpha_range];
}
-(void)updateUI
{
    emTV = [[EMAccordionTableViewController alloc] initWithTable:remarksTable];
    [emTV setDelegate:self];
    [self addCustomBackButtonWithNaviBarColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"#c3b395" alpha:1.0f]];
    //[self addCustomBackButton];
    if (IS_IOS7)
    {
        [remarksTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    [self addCustomBackButtonWithNaviBarColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"#006666" alpha:1.0f]];
    NSMutableArray *menuindex = (NSMutableArray *)[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:@"menuindexarray"];
    [self addCutomTitleToCustomNavigationBar:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[(NSMutableArray *)[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:@"appnamearray"]objectAtIndex:[[menuindex objectAtIndex:[(NSString *)[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:@"selmenuitem"]integerValue]]integerValue]]]];
    currentDate=[NSDate date];
    globalDate=currentDate;
    calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    //today = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NHWunits fromDate:currentDate];
    defaultDateInteger=components.day;
    [self fillcalendar];
    //  [self getdate];
   // [self dateSelectedInPickerView];
    [self getRemarks];

}
-(void)getRemarks
{
    if ([self connected])
    {
        [self showLoadingViewWithMessage:@"Loading..."];
        [[DPSAppService sharedInstance] getDataFromURL:[self getURL] responseBlock:^(NSDictionary *response)
         {
             if (response)
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",response);
                 homewokArray = [response valueForKey:@"studentassignment"];
                 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                 [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
                 NSDate *CurrentDate =[NSDate date];
                 NSString *cDate =[df stringFromDate:CurrentDate];
                 NSLog(@" current Month date is: %@",cDate);
                 collectHW =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                 for (int i=0; i<homewokArray.count; i++)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"New data is: %@",[[homewokArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date"]);
                     if ([cDate isEqualToString:[[homewokArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"date"]])
                     {
                         [collectHW addObject:[homewokArray objectAtIndex:i]];

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSLog(@"No Homework today");
                     }

                 }
                 NSLog(@"Current data of homework is: %@",collectHW);


                 if (homewokArray.count==0)
                 {
                     [self showDropDownViewWithmessage:@"No homework is yet to display." title:@"Message" inView:self.view];
                 }else
                 {

                        [self CreateSection];
                     //   [self showHomework];

                 }

             }
             else
             {

                 [self showDropDownViewWithmessage:SERVER_ERROR title:ERROR inView:self.view];
             }
             [self hideLoadingViewWithSuccessMessage:LOGIN_SUCCESS];

             [self addBottomView];
         }];
    }
    else
    {


    }
}


-(NSString *)getURL
{


    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@classid=%@&academciyearid=%@&sectionid=%@",[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:@"baseerpurl"],URL,STUDENT_HOMEWORK,[[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:STUDENT_DATA_JSON ]valueForKey:@"classid"],[[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:STUDENT_DATA_JSON ]valueForKey:@"academciyearid"],[[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:STUDENT_DATA_JSON ]valueForKey:@"sectionid"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: on which line is it giving error, try using exceptional breakpoint and see which array is nil

Comment: where is
 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView & 

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Sir actually i am using Accordion so there is no need to use no of rows and no of section

Comment: Have you hardcoded the number of rows by any chance?? I dont see that method -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: No sir i have not only i am using predefine accordion files

Answer (score 0):

Add exceptional breakpoint and see how many objects are there in Array and from which index an object being taken out from that array,by doing this you will be able to find out and sort out the problem :)

Comment: Now i have find the thread using add exceptional breakpoint . the error is in height for header in section. now i have given static value but now the cell is displaying two section instead of one

Comment: In general it should not be,but please once check by explicitly defining numberOfSection method and return one.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to return the correct value in numberOfRowsInSection method. GENERALLY, that value is the count of an array. If this is also your case then please debug your flow and check for inconsistencies. Whenever the count of the array is altered or changed, the tableview should be reloaded.